# ld cannot find 'GLESv2' library

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, linker, cross-compiling

I'm tring to cross-compiling qt 5.7.1 for raspberry pi 3 model B from a arch linux (64bits) host.
So, in this purpose, I'm following this tutorial : https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=204529#p1269019 .
But, when i execute these commands in the "/opt/qt5pi/qt5build/" directory :

```
../qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.1/configure -no-use-gold-linker -opengl es2 -device linux-rpi3-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /opt/qt5pi/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwebengine -skip qtscript -nomake examples -make libs

make
```

The linker tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld send this error :

```
ld: cannot find -lGLESv2
```

Answer (score 0):

@allebas, I had your same problem and I hope this could be useful:

1) First on my `.pro` I had to link all necessary libraries, be careful because the order of the include is very very important, see below an example from an old project I have:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt
SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

LIBS += -L "/usr/include/libdrm" \
        -lglfw -lrt -lm -ldl -lGLEW -lGLU -lGLESv2 -lGL \
        -lpthread -pthread -ldrm -lXdamage -lXfixes -xcb \
        -lxcb-glx -lxcb-dri2 -lXxf86vm -lXext -lX11 -lpthread -lxcb \
        -lXau -lXdmcp -lXcursor -lglut -lXrandr
```

2) if after double checking that this specific library is not installed on your system, then the following step should help you install the missing library(ies):

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev libgles2-mesa-dev
```

3) See also the [following source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809236/how-to-develop-opengl-es-gles-2-0-applications-on-linux/39356268#39356268) as it explains how to do all installation steps if some library is still missing on your system

Comment: thank you for your answer. Actually, I decide to change of tutorial. I just followed this tutorial : https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS#Step_by_step . And it works for me !