# Running Flutter on Kria KR260 : crash in GL proc resolver

Tags: flutter, opengl-es

I am trying to run flutter on a small arm board by xilinx, a Kria KR260. No GPU, but the software rendering should be sufficient. Can create and build application without problems. But, when running, I got a crash at startup.
`[FATAL:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl_delegate.cc(52)] Check failed: gl_get_string. The GL proc resolver could not resolve glGetString`

Using ubuntu 22.04.
Followed the step here to make sure the board work correctly : [Booting Kria Starter Kit Linux on KR260¶](https://xilinx.github.io/kria-apps-docs/kr260/build/html/docs/kria_starterkit_linux_boot.html)

I then install flutter using snap. Version 3.18.0-7.0.pre.7.

Try searching a bit for the error. Found only answer saying to use open-source driver for nvidia. No nvidia here, so not the solution I need.

I wanted to make sure I can use OpenGLES on the board. Use the source code from an answer here: [GLFW, Mesa, Ubuntu 16.04 AMD64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39356268/2207845).
I try the code on a WSL in windows to check it first (mostly since the answer is a bit old). Work perfectly like that, with this compile command line:
`gcc glfw_triangle.c -lGLESv2 -lglfw`

Try the same thing on the board. Compile correctly. But, the window is completely empty, and the glGetString return are 'null'. Ah similar to flutter error!
After a lot of test, found that if I change the compile line to:
`gcc glfw_triangle.c -lGLESv2 -lglfw -lGL`
The window now show correctly, and the version string is correct:
`OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1`

Now I am not sure I this found is helpful or not, only that it show that OpenGL WORK on the board.

I try forcing to use the GL lib when compiling my app, by adding
`target_link_libraries(${BINARY_NAME} PRIVATE GL)`
in CMakeLists.txt. Did not change anything. Since the call is not directly glGetString, but a gl resolver I did not think it would, but better to try it.